# How can I add separate line to my chart in recharts which will be connected with previous line?

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I have a realization you may see on the screenshot. But this two separate lines is not connected to each other even if the end value of the first line is the same as start on the second line [see the Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIS4m.png)

I've attached codesandbox realization I had made https://codesandbox.io/s/two-separate-lines-wet8f9

I have created two separate  components with different data objects. The first one doesn't contain the data from the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the correct data array. Each object in `data` renders a point in the chart. However, your `mergedData` duplicates Page E.

```
[...data, ...data2]

// ->
...
{name: "Page E", uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
{name: "Page E", uv: 1890, pv2: 4800, amt: 2181},
...
```

So the chart renders 2 different points in X with the same name.

What you want is a single point with both `pv` and `pv2` values:

```
{
  name: "Page E",
  pv: 4800,
  pv2: 4800,
}
```

[image]

Sidenote: for clarity you can remove `uv` and `amt` since there are no `Line` assigned for those `data-key`.

Comment: The solution looks much simpler than I imagined. Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The only answer for myself I figured out during some experiments
https://codesandbox.io/s/two-separate-lines-forked-lmjlzy?file=/src/App.tsx

If you have more apropriate solution, it would be great to see it